# Is there a common method for implementing pagination through PHP data objects?

Tags: php, oop, class, pagination

I am going to be implementing a small custom CMS for a website.  I was wondering if there are any more popular methods for implementing pagination using OOP.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOP is very general question. You can design your CMS in a hundred OOP and non-OOP ways. Well, this is the common scenario, how pagination works:

**In your controller:**

A. Extract total count of rows in the table

> list($total_rowcount) =
> $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM table
> WHERE ...");

B. Define total page count (in the table)

> $page_count = ceil($total_rowcount /
> $rowcount_per_page);

C. Extract rows for the current selected page

> $start_element = $page *
> $rowcount_per_page;
>
> $end_element = $start_element + $rowcount_per_page;
>
> $rows = $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM table
> WHERE ... LIMIT " . $start_element  . ',' . $end_element );

**In the template**

D. show all elements

> $rowcount_per_page = count($rows);
>
> for ($i = 0; $i < $rowcount_per_page; $i++)
>
> {  show( $rows[$i] ); }

E. Show all page links

> for ($i = 0; $i < $page_count; $i++)
>
> { echo ($i == $page ? $i : '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>'); }

That's it.